# Nav component deeplink do not do conditional navigation

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-deep-link, android-navigation-graph

I am using navcomponent deeplink option to deeplink from a universal link to my app screen.

Step 1 : added the deeplink param in main_nav_graph file

Step 2:  added  to manifest file of my mainactivity

Step 3:  clicked on the link on a SMS to launch the deeplink

Scenarios seen:

in my app SplashActivity is the Main Launcher . But Main Activity is where navgraph is initialised.  So i added the navgraph tag for main activity in Manifest

Main Activity is added as single task.

Now when i deeplink i see :

1. my mainactivity is resumed 2 times ( looks like app launch then close then launch again and deeplink to the screen)
2. If user is not logged in, i have a condition check to stay at navigation root view.  But i see that it still navigates to the deeplink screen creating abnormal scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Navigation 2.1.0-alpha06 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0-alpha06):

> Navigation now suppresses the animation that occurs when recreating the activity when handling a deep link, fixing a visual flash. ([b/130362979](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130362979))

So you should upgrade to Navigation 2.1.0 (currently `2.1.0-rc01` to fix the visual glitch).

Secondly, as per the [conditional navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional), you should **not** be using the login screen as the root of your graph. Instead, every destination that requires login should redirect users to the login screen if the user is not logged in. This is precisely to avoid the case you are experiencing: you want the user to be immediately sent to the correct deep linked screen with the correct back stack.

Comment: 1. i upgraded the version to 2.1.0. I see the animation glitch is gone. But i can still see MainActivity being recreated twice from debug logs. Since animation is gone visually looks fine, but still wonder why is the activity created twice.
2. As per the answer . i had a login fragment as my startdestination if user is not authenticated. I had removed that start destination and updated. But i still see the deeplink going to the screen in case of unauthenticated scenario. @ianhanniballake

Comment: It is expected that the activity is recreated if you get an intent with `NEW_TASK` and not `CLEAR_TASK`. It is also expected that you go the deep link destination. Like I said, it is up to every destination that requires login to redirect the user to the login destination if the user isn't logged in (either because they never logged in, their login expired, or they deleted their account, whatever).

Comment: so here i have 5 tabs. i reworked on a single tab for now (removing loginfragment from the root and keeping tab1 fragment as start destination. then in that fragment i check if user not logged in, i redirect to loginfragment.  app still works fine when i altered this flow.  But i see that when i deeplink to 2 level down in that tab1 e.g   Tab1fragment - fragment 2 - fragment 3(deeplink location) .  In mainactivity onNewIntent am checking if user not logged in , redirect to loginfragment.  But still i see that deeplink to fragment 3. even after removing the login fragment from root level

Comment: myunderstanding is that if i remove loginfragment the startdestination and root level of graph. I would be able to intercept the deeplink inside my Mainactivity onNewIntent() and stop the deeplink .. instead redirect to my login fragment. If that not the case, then are u saying that in all the deeplink candidate fragment..i need to add this logged in check?  @ianhanniballake

Comment: @Sunil - that's what I've said multiple times, yes.

Comment: ok , got it. so then removing loginfragment as start destination is not required if it still deeplinks to the destfragment.  i just need to manually handle the check on each of my destination fragment to redirect user to loginfragment if he is not logged in .. and avoid any checks in mainactivity

Comment: @Sunil - having the login fragment as your start destination is 1) unnecessary if you're redirecting users 2) slows down the 99% of the already logged in case 3) breaks NavigationUI and `navigateUp()` that assume you're following the Principles of Navigation and aren't popping the start destination off your back stack. That's why the Principles of Navigation docs specifically say not to do that.

Comment: now i wish to ask if i have 2 navgraphs in my app Mainactivity , FullActivity hosting 2 navgraphs. If i try to deeplink to a fragment which is available in my 2nd navgraph . I think even handling this condition check doesnt work well.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I don't think developers like this approach of handing things at the destination. I have read many articles where developers try to set up things before opening application and many of them end up using separate activity for login.

Comment: @uberchilly - even if you use a separate activity, you absolutely must check whether you are logged in at every destination as per the documentation and the [Navigating Navigation video](https://youtu.be/09qjn706ITA?t=272).

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes but if you catch all deep link intents in login activity and pass them to main, if user is logged in + kill login when navigating, and let main activity execute deep link intent on nav graph, you will not have login in the back stack. Plus I use retrofit interceptor approach to handling token expiration which is one place where I catch token invalid error for all requeats  and signal to the rest of the app that it needs to clear stack and jump to login activity again

Comment: @uberchilly - the video also talks about why that's a terrible idea and how your approach is throwing away the user's state - something the actual recommended approach does not do.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I currently don't have deep link in the app just trying to speculate and find solution. Tnx for the help. I think I see what you mean about losing state